# Add custom validator which only applies to first element of $each in vuelidate

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuelidate

I'm trying to use `Vuelidate` to controll the inputs of my form. I'm providing an input field for the `firstname`, the `lastname`, the `nationality` and the `age` of the customer.

In my application it's necessary to check if the first customer is at least 18 years old.

I've tried the following to do this:

```
validations: {
        customers: {
            $each: {
                firstName: { required, minLength: minLength(2), maxLength: maxLength(35) },
                lastName: { required, minLength: minLength(2), maxLength: maxLength(35) },
                nationality: { required }, 
                age: {
                    isFirstCustomerValid: (value) => {
                        return value >= 18
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Now the problem is that this applies to all customers which is not intended. Is there a way to only access the first element of the $each property?

Answer (score 1):

You can try finding customer's index by 2 ways:

- If you customer has unique id, then use:

  ```
    const customerIndex = this.customers.findIndex(c => c.id === customer.id)
  ```
- If not, you can try using lodash's method [isEqual](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#isEqual)

  ```
  const customerIndex = this.customers.findIndex(c => _.isEqual(c, customer))
  ```

Code sample:

```
validations: {
  customers: {
      $each: {
          firstName: { required, minLength: minLength(2), maxLength: maxLength(35) },
          lastName: { required, minLength: minLength(2), maxLength: maxLength(35) },
          nationality: { required }, 
          age: {
              isFirstCustomerValid: (value, customer) => {
                 // if your customer has valid unique id, you can find it by findIndex
                const customerIndex = this.customers.findIndex(c => c.id === customer.id)

                 // OR you ccan try lodash library 'isEqual' method (https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#isEqual)
                const customerIndex = this.customers.findIndex(c => _.isEqual(c, customer))

                return customerIndex || value >= 18
              }
          }
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice @ittus. I've added an `id` property in `customer` and tried your first suggestion. 

I'm getting this error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'customers' of undefined`

Do you know what causes this error? `customers` is load from my store in `...mapState`.